# Отображение репутации на мете

Tags: поддержка, репутация, мета

[image: Скриншот репутации на мете]

Каким образом формируется это число?

Comment: Откуда у тебя вообще мета в списке? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy Кажется, их можно добавлять, если нажать на кнопку `править` справа от надписи `ваши сообщества`.

Comment: Это из-за кривого кода. По-другому объяснить не могу. У меня тоже самое. И это точно не из-за кеша.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik А число у Вас другое?

Comment: @nomnoms12 ага. 30.801/30.606

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, а это метарепутацией не может быть?

Comment: @nomnoms12, я так и не понял, где настраивать.

Comment: @Qwertiy не. Они должны быть одинаковыми. Там же [кнопка](https://monosnap.com/file/OTEbut0ndMcrhA5udFfskXsXPOhbH2) есть.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, а я вот тут искал: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/hidecommunities/178988

Comment: [А у меня все путем  с отображением на мете ;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qECi0.png)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, так отличаются же циферки

Comment: У меня вообще на > 6000 отличаются

Comment: Баг https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382603/bug-reputation-stack-overflow-meta-and-main-site-more-than-30-days-different

Comment: @Андрей NOP Ну на мете репа перестраивается не сразу, тогда и на ней отображалось 2835.

Comment: У меня сейчас активность нулевая, 6к репы я набрал, наверное, за последние года полтора, вы хотите сказать, что это она никак не перестроится? @Victor

Comment: @Андрей NOP Да нет, это я ошибся, просто как отдельное сообщество мети я добавил себе специально, чтобы проверить, как у меня сработает, так вообще я перехожу по боковым вопросам ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема старая. Я писал об этом уже больше года назад: [Significant reputation difference among meta and main sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322592/339911). Но даже в том случае это оказалось дубликатом на ещё более старый вопрос: [Meta sites in "Your Communities" display different reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation).

В качестве примера приведу мои значения:

> [image: Репа и мета-репа]

На сайте "Русский язык" я практически неактивен. Репа совпадает.

На enSO разница удивительным образом совпадала с числом указанным на вкладке активности (привожу картинку с ruSO, т.к. на enSO я не успел вовремя сделать скрин и уже посетил вкладку репутации, что сбросило показания):

> [image: с момента последнего визита на вкладку репутации]

На ruSO разница > 2000 реп. Такую разницу даже не получается объяснить недавним пересчётом репутации за вопросы (стали давать +10, вместо +5), т.к. у меня просто не наберётся такого кол-ва голосов в вопросах.

Здесь явно имеет место быть какой-то баг, вероятно, связанный с кешированием значений репутации между основным и мета сайтами. О наличии такого кеширования легко убедиться, когда на основном сайте меняется репутация, то на мета-сайте даже в шапке значение отстаёт. Но вот почему эти значения в некоторых случаях разъезжаются уже так долго сказать могут только разработчики после анализа бага. Но, как видим, ответа от них нет, да и вряд ли будет в ближайшее время. Всё-таки мета-сайты вторичны, реальной репутации на них нет и от этого отображаемого значения ничего не зависит. Короче говоря, баг минорный и специально его вряд ли будут править.