# Суммируются ли баллы на мете и баллы на основном сайте?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, мета

Суммируются ли баллы на мете и баллы на основном сайте?

Comment: В теории, они должны совпадать. Репутация основного сайта дублируется на Мете. Но есть с этим [баг](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10311/15479).

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik если я получаю баллы здесь, то они добавляются к основному профилю?

Comment: Не. Работает только в обратную сторону. На Мете, как таковой, репы нет. Просто отображается репа основного сайта.

Comment: А жаль, было бы круто

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> На Мете, как таковой, репы нет. Просто отображается репа основного сайта.